# Meaning of 真逆, how it is different from 逆

Tags: words, slang

`[真]{ま}[逆]{ぎゃく}` (not `[真]{ま}[逆]{さか}`, which is an interjection standardly used) is another 若者言葉, or an expression that is used mainly by young generation (with low education level) that makes me feel uncomfortable.

`逆` is a polarity notion; Something can be either the original (`元`), or the opposite (`逆`). There is no intermediate values like "half-way opposite", hence no room for quantitative/qualitative notions like genuine (`真`) or fake/quasi (`偽`) to come into play. I have no idea what meaning `真` is adding to `逆`. How is `真逆` different from `逆`? How would you justify the addition of `真` to `逆`?

Comment: I always thought it was something similar to adding 真っ to 逆さま and 正 to 反対... the reading of まぎゃく sounds awkward to me though.

Comment: Just another thought: does slang have to be justified?

Comment: An analogous argument to yours seems to deny the difference between 反対 and 正反対.  In fact, I have been assuming that まぎゃく is a slang for 正反対 and so far it seems that this assumption has been good enough to understand the intent of the speaker.

Comment: I agree with Chocolate and TsuyoshiIto that the same argument applies to 真っ逆さま and 正反対. And I actually do wonder the same thing with these examples, although it is true that I do not feel discomfort with these examples as I do with 真逆, and am wondering why I feel different.

Comment: Perhaps you dislike it because (a) it is new, and associated with a sociolect you dislike, and/or (b) it is a (native) Japanese prefix attached to a Sino-Japanese morpheme, which is not unheard of but less common than other patterns.

Comment: @Matt I think you are right.

Comment: Could it be that the expression comes from wilfully mis-pronouncing the (somewhat rare) kanji spelling of まさか? In fact, when I read your post, I assumed you were talking about 真逆【まさか】until I saw comments referring to まぎゃく.
Anyway, まさか is standard Japanese (afaik), and まぎゃく roughly means the same... So it would make sense to me, but maybe I am completely missing the point.

Comment: @Dave Yes. I was referring to まぎゃく. When it is read as まさか, it is like an interjection, and means a different thing.

Comment: @sawa: Yes, I got that from the comments... But precisely: while I'm not very familiar with まぎゃく, its meaning seems to be "exact/very opposite", whereas まさか means something along the line of "by no means!, never!" (basically, an exclamation of denial)... Although they serve very different grammatical functions, I don't see their meanings as so different (and it could have explained how the slang term came to be). But that was only an observation and a wild guess...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`真逆` seems very similar to the expression "total opposite" in English.

I think we can take `真` here to be an intensifier/emphasis rather than something that affects the meaning. It emphasizes that something is not just `少し違う`, but in fact `逆`.

I'd even say that not even `真逆` requires you to be absolutely precise. Let's say someone wanted to head east (0°). West (180°) would be `逆`. If you saw them going in essentially entirely the wrong direction -- almost due west -- you might want to use `真逆` to emphasize how badly they're going wrong, **even if** their true course isn't **exactly** 180°.

It's an abuse of terminology, technically, but I think this is how the language is used.