# What is the meaning of the word "ma" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

The sentence is: まピンクの きのこが 生えた or ma pinku no kinoko  ga haeta.

(I think it means "A pink mushroom grew".)

What does the ま at the beginning of the sentence mean?

Thank you!

Comment: Related (dupe?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5032/5010

Comment: Can you please explain to me how these two questions are related? I can't find any similarities?

Comment: ま=真. so まピンク means "really pink" or "totally pink" as suggested by the linked question.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry even after reading it again that conclusion whooshed over my head!

Comment: I don't think this is really a duplicate question; at least not a duplicate of the currently linked answer.  The linked answer is too tightly linked with 逆 and so I think the OP is rightly confused.  It'd probably be better if we had an answer (or linked answer, if it exists) that clearly focuses on 真 as its primary concern.

Comment: I would like to suggest the title of this question be rewritten as "Meaning of ま as a prefix", the question be re-opened, and an answer provided that explains the various uses of 真 in this and other contexts.

Comment: `Isn't it so much easier to just answer this kind of question than look for possible duplicates.. ` 簡単かどうかという問題ではなくて、このSEというサイトの目標というのが[ここに書かれている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tour)ように we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the Japanese language. We're a little bit different from other sites... ということで、以前に解決したものと同じ質問は duplicate として close してくださいというのもサイトの方針ですしその理由も[ここに書かれて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)います